# How to add **Test Details** for testers in TestFlight while releasing a flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

How to add **Test Details** for testers in TestFlight while releasing a flutter app?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your TestFlight section of the Apple Developer account you can add Beta - Testing information under "General Information" -> "Test information".